# Schedule a gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to run a gcloud command automatically once a day.

The command is

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://{my_location}
```

What is the best way to do this? The only idea I have so far is to create some cloud function in python that calls that command and then set up cloud scheduler to raise the HTTP request.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a Cloud Storage export using cron jobs and the Cloud SDK. For detailed steps visit the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#deploying_the_cron_job). Same can be done in Cloud Firestore by setting up the [cron.yaml](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#cronyaml) file:

```
    cron:
    - description: "Daily Cloud Firestore Export"   
      url: /cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://BUCKET_NAME[/PATH]
      target: cloud-firestore-admin   
      schedule: every 24 hours
```

The other solution is to raise the [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments) HTTP Request via the Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you for that link, the issue though is you have to deploy an app to do this. I just want to run my single line

Comment: In such case, as you've been suspecting, I'd recommend to use Cloud Scheduler to raise the POST HTTP request documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments